# How do I read a file in python and numpy and create an output file without having to manually change the name of the input file in the code?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to read a text file which has an arbitrary amount of columns with numbers.

I want to manipulate the data and then create an output file.

My code is :

```
import numpy as np

array=np.loadtxt('filename.txt')

#multiply first column by 2 
array[:,0]=array[:,0]*2

savetxt('filename2.txt',array)
```

I want to just run the code on filename without having to type the filename in the code manually every time.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: make it to take filename as param from cmd or other place

Comment: you must use an `openfiledialog()` method to be able to point where the file is located, instead of manually writing it.

Comment: please format the code in your post to make it easier to read.

Comment: What do you mean by "type the filename manually"? Is this a script or do you run an interactive session? Is the file name fixed, or does it depend on user input?

Answer (score 0):

Use the package glob, it will take all the files in a directory with a certain type of extension and allow you to use their data. Essentially you will just have a folder you drop your text files into before running the program.

```
import glob
x = []
for filename in glob.iglob('/Path_to_Directory/*.txt'): #Takes all text files in folder
     x.append(filename)

for i in x: #Loop through all folders in directory 
    with open (i, 'rU') as infile:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import numpy as np
fname1 = sys.argv[1]
fname2 = sys.argv[2]
arr = np.loadtxt(fname1)
np.savetxt(fname2, arr * 2)
```

then run your code:

```
python myscript.py inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! So sys is a module in python  that allows me to interactively apply my code to a file without having to manually change the name in my code correct?

Comment: from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html   --- This module provides access to some variables used or maintained by the interpreter and to functions that interact strongly with the interpreter.  sys is broader than your statement, but sys.argv is the list of arguments that were supplied when the interpreter was first executed

Comment: p.s. your question as written is a little vague, and all 3 answers are valid within the scope of your question.  You could consider re-writing your question to be more specific and then 'Accept' the answer that most closely answers it it appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the filename to a variable, and use that in the function calls.

```
import numpy as np
filename = 'filename.txt'  # or get it from input
data=np.loadtxt(filename)
data[:,0]=data[:,0]*2
np.savetxt(filename, data)  # reuse the filename variable (string)
```